# Why does JavaScript always have the most 'recent' questions on the home page, but not on the tags page?

Tags: discussion, tags

On the Stack Overflow homepage, on the right side, I see a bar with 'Recent Tags'. Usually, JavaScript has the most 'recent' on them, but then when I go to the Tags page, JavaScript usually has less 'recent' or 'asked this week' questions than Java or C#. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: How are you ordering the questions on the tags page?

Comment: @Oded by 'popular'

Comment: Well, there you go. Popular != newest. It means those with lots of views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I get it now. Basically, I was looking at the total views, not total number of questions. I thought 'popular' was total number of questions,